Adjusting the Origin of Rolling Costmaps in ROS2 Nav2 for Forward Offset
I am trying to adjust the origin of both global and local rolling costmaps to be positioned in front of the vehicle instead of centering the robot within them. Despite setting the origin_x and origin_y parameters, the costmaps do not seem to reposition as expected.

Correspondent snniptet of code from configuration file:
# GPS WPF CHANGE: Remove static layer
local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0 #20.0 #5.0 
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      rolling_window: true
      width: 80
      height: 20
      origin_x: 50.0  # Shifts the costmap back by 75 meters
      origin_y: 0.0  # No lateral shift
      track_unknown_space: true

for global costmap:
global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      #unknown_cost_value: 120 #255 #0# slightly less than 255 to be more explorative
      lethal_cost_threshold: 100 
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      #use_sim_time: True
      #robot_radius: 5.0 #0.22
      footprint:  "[[-4.8025, -1.739], [4.8025, -1.739], [4.8025, 1.739], [-4.8025, 1.739]]"
      resolution: 1.0 #0.05 # Increased tge resoluiton to 1 meter for 1 grid, since the truck is much bigger than turtlebot size, and 0.1 was default for turtlebot.
      # When using GPS navigation you will potentially traverse huge environments which are not practical to
      # fit on a big static costmap. Thus it is recommended to use a rolling global costmap large enough to 
      # contain each pair of successive waypoints. See: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/2174
      rolling_window: True
      width: 200
      height: 40
      origin_x: 100.0  # Shifts the costmap back by 75 meters
      origin_y: 0.0  # No lateral shift
      track_unknown_space: true

Configuration Attempts:

I've tried adjusting origin_x and origin_y for both global and local
costmaps.
Checked lifecycle states and parameters to ensure they are set
correctly.

The lifecycle status was active as well as the parameters were correctly set (not default, which is 0.0)
rota_2024@Rota:~/nav2_gps_ws$ ros2 param get /global_costmap/global_costmap origin_x
Double value is: 100.0
rota_2024@Rota:~/nav2_gps_ws$ ros2 param get /global_costmap/global_costmap origin_y
Double value is: 100.0
rota_2024@Rota:~/nav2_gps_ws$ ros2 param get /local_costmap/local_costmap origin_x
Double value is: 50.0
rota_2024@Rota:~/nav2_gps_ws$ ros2 param get /local_costmap/local_costmap origin_y
Double value is: 50.0
/ros2 lifecycle set /global_costmap/global_costmap configure
/ros2 lifecycle set /global_costmap/global_costmap activate
Unknown transition requested, available ones are:
- deactivate [4]
- shutdown [7]

Issue:
Despite the parameters being set, the costmap's origin does not appear to shift forward as intended in a rolling_window configuration. The truck remains centered.
Questions:

Is there a known limitation or specific method to set the origin
offset for rolling windows in Nav2?
How can I ensure the costmap repositions its origin effectively when
using rolling_window settings?
Are there additional steps or configurations needed to achieve a
forward-offset costmap in Nav2?

Any advice or insights from those familiar with ROS2 and Nav2's advanced configurations would be greatly appreciated!
